# Adding a white box with four image buttons to a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This my current layout for a detail view of a JSON object:

[image]

And this is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

   

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/strImagen"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombreEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/strMano"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

   

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/direccionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nombreEmpresa"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/strMano"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombreEmpresa"
        
        android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/strMano"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/valoracionEmpresa"
        android:src="@drawable/valoracion" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textOferta"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="descripcion descripcion descripcion descripcion descripcion "
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horarioEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="horario horario horario horario"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOferta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:maxLines="15"
        android:text="dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dad"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

  

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying, without success to include the bottom part, the box with white background and the four image buttons.

I need your help to create the needed part of the layout. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `LinearLayout` with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and add it inside your parent `RelativeLayout`. This will make sure the layout is placed bottom of the parent layout.

Add this layout inside

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/strMano">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your external Relative Layout in a Linear Layout that has vertical orientation.
After your Relative Layout, add another Linear Layout (now horizontally oriented) and Image Buttons inside it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:padding="3dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/strImagen"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />
        </LinearLayout>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombreEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/strMano"
            android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/direccionEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/nombreEmpresa"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/strMano"
            android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="10dip" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombreEmpresa"

            android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="5:45"
            android:textColor="#10bcc9"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/strMano"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/valoracionEmpresa"
            android:src="@drawable/valoracion" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textOferta"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="descripcion descripcion descripcion descripcion descripcion "
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/horarioEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="horario horario horario horario"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOferta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/descripcionEmpresa"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:maxLines="15"
            android:text="dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dsdasdadsa sdasdad asdasdasdasd dad"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        // Insert your image buttons

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, what you have posted is not working as it is now.